# Create own flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, plugins

I would be glad if someone can point me a direction on creating own plugin. Let's say at first I have a dart class that will make a few api calls, basically are configurations apis from a server.

```
class Api {
Future<dynamic> getConfig() async {
  var response = await http.get(url, headers:header)
  return response;
}
```

But now I tend to make it into a plugin, for the other projects to use. But after I read on some tutorial on how to create plugin for flutter. I am a bit unclear on the structure. From what I have read, after created a plugin project, a lib, android, ios, and example directories will be created. File inside lib included this default code

```
static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
  final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
  return version;
}
```

And the *getPlatformVersion* method is located in both **android** and **ios** folder, it has two different implementation written in java and objective c, but they do the same thing.

So my question is, does it mean that I need to write two different apis calling implementations for both ios (like NSURLConnection) and android (AsyncHttpClient )? Can't seem to find any answer out there.

Comment: Yes, with a plugin (compared to a package) you provide a Dart API and implementations in iOS and Android (and possibly macOS and web). Plugins are used to access platform specific features. A package is Dart only code and implements a feature/algorithm that can be coded entirely in Dart. Both are reusable. Depend on a package or plugin by adding it to `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for replying. But, since I can successfully makes apis call using dart language only, possibly that I can remain everything inside dart file in lib folder, only if when I require a native api, I call the method and implement native code? U get what I mean?

Comment: If you only have Dart code, make a package. If you have a mixture, make a plugin. In a plugin in you can of course have much logic in pure Dart, too.

Comment: @RichardHeap sorry late reply, thanks.

Comment: @RichardHeap hi, I have another question regarding package. From official side, i know can import package from pubspec, but is that is folder path/git url right? My question is, can package compile into maybe a jar to pass around to other people?